# Trying to install a package, but getting this Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requireents bidict==0.22.1

Tags: python

Trying to install Kotak APi package, but getting this error. I am using this command: pip install "git+https://github.com/Kotak-Neo/kotak-neo-api.git#egg=neo_api_client". Here is the link to the documentation: https://github.com/Kotak-Neo/kotak-neo-api

Someone please help:

[image]